# How to register Notification directly for Alert and not just Banner? Swift or Objective C in XCode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, push-notification

That's how i register my local notifications:

```
 if application.respondsToSelector(#selector(UIApplication.registerUserNotificationSettings(_:))) {
            if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
                let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
                let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: categoriesForSettings as! Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>)
                application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            } else {
                application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
            }
}
else 
{
            // Register for Push Notifications before iOS 8
            application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])
}
```

My Problem is that the notification comes in as a Banner. Only after the user changes the settings of the application from Banner to Alert the Notification comes in as a real Alert.

My Question is: Is it possible to ask or register directly for the real Alert and not only the Banner notification?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: its in user's hand. User only change it in the settings page.

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Are you 100% sure?

Comment: yes, sure @Jonas schafft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it can't be changed from code.